# Android YouTube Data API search.execute() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-data-api

I'm not new to Java but I am new to developing on Android Studio and their platform along with the YouTube Data API and I'm having a problem with the app crashing due to the line `SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();`
this is causing me a little frustration and I would like some help as it will help me learn and proceed with my project rather than giving up.

```
try {
         youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
              public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
         }).build();

        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

        search.setKey(youtubeKey);
        search.setQ(s);
        search.setType("video");

        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
        search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);
        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute(); // line that crashes app
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();

        if (searchResultList != null) {

            Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults = searchResultList.iterator();

            while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
                SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
                ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

                if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                    name.add(singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
                    desc.add(singleVideo.getSnippet().getDescription());
                    image.add(singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl());
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logcat where everything goes red (error)

> 01-18 00:01:24.266 11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest E/InputEventSender:
>   Exception dispatching finished signal. 01-18 00:01:24.267
>   11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in
>   MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 01-18 00:01:24.373
>   11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source:0)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.connect(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:128)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.connect(HttpsURLConnection$.java:366)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>                                                                                        at
>   dylanhedger.yttest.MainActivity$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1259)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.SearchView.-wrap8(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.SearchView$5.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1236)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7226)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7095)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:831)
>                                                                                        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2691)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11713)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:440)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3267)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindow
>   01-18 00:01:24.373 11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM 01-18 00:01:24.417 11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: dylanhedger.yttest, PID: 11928
>                                                                                  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                      at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
>                                                                                      at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
>                                                                                      at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
>                                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
>                                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source:0)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.connect(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:128)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.connect(HttpsURLConnection$.java:366)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>                                                                                      at
>   dylanhedger.yttest.MainActivity$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1259)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.SearchView.-wrap8(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.SearchView$5.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1236)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7226)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7095)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:831)
>                                                                                      at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2691)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11713)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:440)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3267)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
>   01-18 00:01:24.447 11928-11928/dylanhedger.yttest E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.WindowProfilerCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowProfilerCallback.java:52)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:354)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4733)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4326)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4487)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Post your Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I found out everything from a blog and it helped a lot so if anyone else has this problem just read the blog

https://ravinishad.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/video-search-in-android-using-youtube.html?showComment=1516382560722#c4197926916525561564

At the bottom, he shows the source code but in case you don't see it here's the GitHub link

https://github.com/Keshava11/LatentLoader